# Is possible to define a minimum size for a ViewPart or Workbench in Eclipse-RCP?

Tags: java, user-interface, layout, eclipse-rcp

I have an `Eclipse` Application with a `ViewPart` that can't be resized under some width and height.

Is it possible to limit the resizing so that the whole `workbench` can't get smaller than the Point value that I want to set?

This requirement is because of the images inside the `ViewPart`, which can't be hidden.

Now I have the `DIALOG_TRIM` option on the whole `workbench` so it can't be resized, but I've been  asked for maximizing the app, so the minimum size is the problem.

I haven't found in stackoverflow.com anything about doing this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to set minimum size on main `Shell`

```
ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor

    @Override
    public void postWindowCreate() {
        super.postWindowCreate();
       final Shell shell = getWindowConfigurer().getWindow().getShell();
       shell.setMinimumSize(700, 800);
    }
```

Comment: That's just what I needed. Thank you very much.